# TryFrom<&[u8]> trait bound in trait

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement common trait for a bunch of types created from binary data (read from a disk). Majority of trait methods could use default implementations and only conversions etc. would be needed to be implemented separately. I would like to use `TryFrom<&[u8]>` trait for conversions from binary data to my types but I don't know how to express (in the context of trait) that lifetime of `&[u8]` and lifetimes of values of my types created from it are not related. Here is minimal example of the problem.

```rust
use std::convert::TryFrom;

struct Foo;

// Value of Foo can be created from &[u8] but it doesn't borrow anything.
impl TryFrom<&[u8]> for Foo {
    type Error = ();

    fn try_from(v: &[u8]) -> Result<Self, ()> {
        Ok(Foo)
    }
}

trait Bar<'a>
where
    Self: TryFrom<&'a [u8], Error = ()>, // `&` without an explicit lifetime name cannot be used here
{
    fn baz() -> Self {
        let vec = Vec::new();
        Self::try_from(&vec).unwrap() // ERROR: vec does not live long enough (nothing is borrowed)
    }
}
```

Alternative solution would be to make conversions as trait methods but it would be nicer to use common std traits. Is there a way to achieve this? (Or I could use const generics but I don't want to rely on nightly compiler.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want are "higher ranked trait bounds" (HRTB, or simply [hearty boy](https://enet4.github.io/rust-tropes/#hearty-boy)). They look like this: `for<'a> T: 'a`. This example just means: "for every possible lifetime `'a`, `T` must ...". In your case:

```rust
trait Bar
where
    Self: for<'a> TryFrom<&'a [u8], Error = ()>,
```

You can also specify that requirement as super trait bound directly instead of `where` clause:

```rust
trait Bar: for<'a> TryFrom<&'a [u8], Error = ()> { ... }
```

And yes, now it just means that all implementors of `Bar` have to implement `TryFrom<&'a [u8], Error = ()>` for *all* possible lifetimes. That's what you want.

**[Working Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e4c018ea62b45d5b27247ee1fb047428)**

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted. However, I'm not sure what do you mean by advantages of specifying super trait bound directly. I was under impression that using where clause is semantically equivalent (and I think that where version is nicer to read).

Comment: @awdrt Mhhh, interesting. I thought that it had implications on what others could expect from the trait. But I tried it and I couldn't find a difference between `where` and super trait bound. So I removed that remark from my answer. Maybe I just misremembered :D

Comment: In the first example `trait Bar<'a>` should be without lifetime.